# How to split text I want from a file?

Tags: c#

Hi This is Wht I got in a file:

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"  
+CMGL: 6123,"REC READ","+923315266206"  
B confident dat GOD can make a way wen der seems 2 b no way. Even wen your mind may waver, GOD is working bhind d scenes on yur behalf. Have a faith-filled day  
+CMGL: 6122,"REC READ","+923315266206"  
B confident dat GOD can make a way wen der seems 2 b no way. Even wen your mind may waver, GOD is working bhind d scenes on yur behalf. Have a faith-filled day

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just want to get the lines i.e text from the file.Like "B confident........waver".
How do I do it ?

I tried with splitting but I cant get it running.....:)

Comment: If there is only one string you want to split, why don't you split it manually, if there is more than one string to split, you'll need to give more information on the characteristics of the other strings. Please also note that the spelling & grammar in this quote is egregiously awful, and I would plead with you to not duplicate it without corrections.

Comment: re: spelling... maybe it's a new iQuoteTheBible app? :)

Comment: Possibly text message spam of some type.

Comment: +1 to the SMS idea: http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmglCommand.asp

Answer (score 4):

Read the file with a StreamReader and use the ReadLine method, that will read the file one line at a time.

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        // do something with the line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will get you your lines into a string array:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
```

So:

```
lines[2];
lines[4];
```

Will get you those lines.

See the msdn documentation for [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like every line in your sample that is not "valid" includes the text `"+CGML"`.  In that case, this should do the trick:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetText(string filePath)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string line;
        while ( (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           if (line.IndexOf("+CMGL") < 0) yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use the streamReader to read in the lines and use a Regex to match certain lines...if there is a pattern you want to match.

example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex pattern = new Regex("^B");
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
         Match patternMatch = pattern.Match(blah);

            if (patternMatch.Groups.Count > 0)
            {
                lines.Add(blah);
            }
    }
}
```